# Binning character variable

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have `class` variable which is concatenation of `marital`, `gender`, and `age` (e.g. MM32). I'd like to group them so the final output would like the following:

```
Class ClassGrp
SM20  SM20-25
SM21  SM20-25
SM22  SM20-25
MF20  MF20-25
MF21  MF20-25
SF30  SF26-30
SF31  SF31-35
```

I have separate columns for `age`, `gender`, and `marital` so my initial process was to break `age` by `cut` function like so `cut(data$Class, breaks = 10)`. But, I can't think of how to transform them to `20-25` format.

**EDIT**

Input Data

```
data <- structure(list(age = c(19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L), gender = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    marital = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Divorced", 
    "Married", "Single", "Widowed"), class = "factor"), class = c("SM19", 
    "SF20", "SM20", "SF21", "SM21", "MF22"), ageGrp = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("(18.9,25]", "(25,31]", "(31,37]", 
    "(37,43]", "(43,49]", "(49,55]", "(55,61]", "(61,67]", "(67,73]", 
    "(73,79.1]"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("age", "gender", 
"marital", "class", "ageGrp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input.

Comment: Where does the Grp part of ClassGrp come from? In the example at the top of your question it's 20-25, 26-30, etc, but in the input data they all have the same ageGrp (18.9 - 25). Is ageGrp supposed to be the Grp part?

Comment: @Hack-R well, I'd like to have it in 20-25, 26-30 and so on but when I use `cut` function I seem to have control over the number of breaks. You can ignore the `ageGrp` since that's not what I want.

Comment: @Ken Oh ok. I didn't see that comment until after my answer, but if you just direct your `cut` to the column of interest (`ageGrp` or some new column) then the solution should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your output bins as a sorted array and check where your value is contained (greater or equal than one, and less than the following).

I've also added a control check, in case your values could be out of your bins (i.e. can be less than the min value, or greater than the max value).

```
# Important: they should be ordered!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "marital", "class", "ageGrp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
my.bins <- c(20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 50, 65)

# Transform into bins
to.bin <- function(class) {
  gender.marital <- substring(class, 1, 2)
  age <- as.numeric(substring(class, 3))
  # Check the boundaries
  if (age < min(my.bins)) {
    return(paste0(gender.marital, "<", min(my.bins)))
  } else if (age >= max(my.bins)) {
    return(paste0(gender.marital, ">=", max(my.bins)))
  }
  lower <- which(my.bins > age)[1]
  return(paste0(gender.marital, my.bins[lower - 1], "-", my.bins[lower] - 1))
}

data$ClassGrp <- sapply(data$class, to.bin)
data
```

The code returns this with your data:

```
  age gender marital class    ageGrp ClassGrp
1  19   Male  Single  SM19 (18.9,25]    SM<20
2  20 Female  Single  SF20 (18.9,25]  SF20-24
3  20   Male  Single  SM20 (18.9,25]  SM20-24
4  21 Female  Single  SF21 (18.9,25]  SF20-24
5  21   Male  Single  SM21 (18.9,25]  SM20-24
6  22 Female Married  MF22 (18.9,25]  MF20-24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Read data
x <- read.table(file = "clipboard")

# Show the data I read in
x

# Bin the data as requested
x$ClassGrp <- as.character(x$ageGrp)
x$ClassGrp <- gsub("\\(", "", x$ClassGrp)
x$ClassGrp <- gsub("\\]", "", x$ClassGrp)
x$ClassGrp <- gsub(",", "-", x$ClassGrp)
x$ClassGrp <- gsub("18.9", "19", x$ClassGrp)
x$g        <- "M"

x$g[x$gender == "Female"] <- "F"
x$m  <- "S"
x$m[x$marital == "Married"] <- "M"

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$ClassGrp[i] <- paste(x$g[i],x$m[i],x$ClassGrp[i], collapse="", sep="")  
}


x$g <- NULL
x$m <- NULL

# Show results
x

   age gender marital class    ageGrp ClassGrp
1   19   Male  Single  SM19 (18.9,25]  MS19-25
2   20 Female  Single  SF20 (18.9,25]  FS19-25
3   20   Male  Single  SM20 (18.9,25]  MS19-25
4   21 Female  Single  SF21 (18.9,25]  FS19-25
5   21   Male  Single  SM21 (18.9,25]  MS19-25
6   22 Female Married  MF22 (18.9,25]  FM19-25
7   22 Female  Single  SF22 (18.9,25]  FS19-25
8   22   Male Married  MM22 (18.9,25]  MM19-25
9   22   Male  Single  SM22 (18.9,25]  MS19-25
10  23 Female Married  MF23 (18.9,25]  FM19-25
```